# don't understand the reason of writing ifstream::in

Tags: c++

```
PortableBitmap(string const &asdf, char qwer, char tyu){

    ifstream fin(textDatei, ifstream::in);

    char c = fin.get();

    fin.close();
}
```

I have a theoritcal question, in the examples on the internet everyone is writing ifstream:: like in the example above. I don't know the reason why we have to write ifstream::in . Can someone explain me and give me an example if there is other way to write it without ifstream::

Giving a related link about this topic also appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have to write ifstream::in.

Comment: It is pretty much unnecessary.. That parameter is mostly used to specify when used with `ifstream`: `std::binary`

Answer (score 3):

No need for `ifstream::`, no need to close the stream at the end of the function either (the ifstream destructor will do that for you). This works exactly the same.

```
PortableBitmap(string const &asdf, char qwer, char tyu)
{
    ifstream fin(textDatei);

    char c = fin.get();
}
```

The second parameter to the ifstream constructor is the 'open mode', you can use it to specify that a stream be opened for reading or writing or both, for binary I/O etc. Not surprsingly the default value for ifstream for the open mode is to open the file for input. So ifstream::in (or equivalently ios_base::in) is not wrong but is unnecessary.

For all the details in the ifstream constructors.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream